# Simple SQLite UPDATE Statement does not work

Tags: database, sqlite

I inserted a new column in my database and want to populate with data. It shall be calculated from the difference of the value of `nom_arr_time` and the value of `nom_dep_time` of the previous row.

If I try to execute the SELECT statement only everything works fine. But the update won't work, the column stays empty.

```sql
UPDATE mobile_statistik 
SET nom_fahrzeit = (SELECT nom_arr_time - LAG(nom_dep_time,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY id) 
                    FROM mobile_statistik);
```

Handling the task through a programming language like python is not an option because of the size, ca. 20GB of the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
UPDATE mobile_statistik 
SET nom_fahrzeit = (
  SELECT t.nom_arr_time - t.prev FROM (
    SELECT id, nom_arr_time, LAG(nom_dep_time,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY id) prev 
    FROM mobile_statistik
  ) t
  WHERE t.id = mobile_statistik.id 
)
```

or without `LAG()`:

```
UPDATE mobile_statistik 
SET nom_fahrzeit = 
  nom_arr_time - (
    SELECT m.nom_dep_time 
    FROM mobile_statistik m 
    WHERE m.id = (SELECT MAX(t.id) FROM mobile_statistik t WHERE t.id < mobile_statistik.id)
  );
```